# Will indexing the email column of a mysql database speed search results?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a large mySQL database with which is constantly executing a SELECT statement searching for a unique email address. Will indexing the email column speed up the returned result? Are there any specific advantages and disadvantages to indexing such a column?

Thanks!

Comment: yes it will. disadvantage = indexes take up space, slow insertion and deletion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Advantages:

1. `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE email = 'foo@bar.com';` Yes.
2. `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE email LIKE 'foo@bar.com';` Yes.
3. `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE email LIKE 'foo@%';` Yes.
4. `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE email LIKE '%@bar.com';` **No.**

String indexes match from left to right, you can wildcard the *end* of a string and still use the index, but not the beginning.

#### Disadvantages:

Note: These are not reasons to avoid putting indexes on necessary columns, but to avoid unnecessarily indexing everything.

- Each time a row is inserted it's one more calculation that must be done.
- Indexes take up space on-disk and in-memory.
- String indexes have a length, eg. they only take into account the first X bytes. By default this is the *entire length of the column* which can put a strain on your CPU if you're constantly calculating indexes on large string columns.

Comment: may like to add `= yes` also; LIKE with out wild-cards is uncommon

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the e-mail column has a type of VARCHAR that is restricted to some reasonable amount, it would be a good idea to try indexing this on a back-up server and then testing it against your live server for metrics.  You should be able to clearly see the benefit.

The disadvantages would come into play if you're constantly INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE-ing as the index has to be updated on any type of data modification (ie, you will experience some bogging as the index is maintained).  Though, this seems it would be negligible if you're doing more reading than writing.  The execution of reads tends to be speed up more than the writes are slowed down.

There's also an increased disk space usage but that tends not to be much of a problem in this new age of ever-expanding storage devices.

Answer (score 0):

"Unique" index will speed up the searching in many times and will guarantee that the all values in the table are unique.
Anyway, take a look at the [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) statement to understand if the query can be optimized.

Comment: non unique ones will speed the search also

Answer (score 0):

I've answered some questions related to yours. I give you some links on the topic:

- [Q: MySQL database optimization using indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253673/mysql-database-optimization-using-indexing/15254042#15254042)
- [Q: SQL Statement - How can Improve speed with indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621128/sql-statement-how-can-improve-speed-with-indexing/15621219#15621219)
- [Q: How to speed up sql queries ? Indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354219/how-to-speed-up-sql-queries-indexes/17354616#17354616)

Punch line: If you are performing frequent searches on a column, it is a good idea (it may be even necesary) to define an index on that column. As Dagon mentions in his comment, indexes take space in your hard drive... but I think that's a fair price to pay.

You may want to take a look to this:

- [MySQL reference manual: How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)
- [MySQL reference manual: Full-text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).
- [MySQL reference manual: Regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

  You may want to take a look to [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318083/mysql-optimization-for-regexp) if you want to know a bit more about regular expressions.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html manual references are always good

Comment: unlikley he wants full text search for an email, but maybe :-)

Comment: but maybe REGEXPs are helpful... adding just now